# ¿ how to record sqlite database on adroid with unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-sqlite

I need to save a database on android but the .sqlite file is not recorded, I create the file as follows:

```
  var path =  Application.persistentDataPath + "/DataBase/homeBrew.sqlite";
   if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path,null);
     }
```

but when I check if the file was saved I get that it doesn't exist and I don't know how to save because with other extensions like .txt if I save the file

Comment: why do you want to save sqlite database in file system. It storage in /data/data/com.packageName.appName/database is security.

Answer (score 0):

First do **never** use `+ "/"` for system file paths.

Rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which automatically inserts the correct path separator symbols according to the OS it is running on:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "DataBase", "homeBrew.sqlite");
```

Not sure if the `null` is the issue but you could also simply use [`File.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create)

```
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Create(path);
}
```

otherwise you could try and use an empty string instead

```
File.WriteAllText(path, string.Empty);
```